# Git difftool --cached and Beyond Compare

Tags: git, github, beyondcompare, beyondcompare3, beyondcompare4

I am using Windows 10. I am diffing 256 files in one folder to 256 files in another I am using the command git difftool --cached to display files in Beyond Compare. The display out put in Git Bash says:

Viewing (1/256): '3-M-ALABAMA-SUIQUARTER2-LABEL.txt'
Launch 'bc' [Y/n]? y

[image]

Which is great so it is showing 256 file differences the problem is that it invokes beyond compare for a file to file compare view 2 files at a time which i do not want because I do not want to generate a report for each file comparison.

So I use the command git difftool --cached --dir-diff and I expect to see in Beyond Compare 256 files on the left and 256 files on right sent from git. Basically I expect it to do the same thing as the command git difftool --cached (but with all the file names listed on each side)

However I only get 86 files on the left and 86 files on the right in Beyond Compare. This is the problem.

My goal is have folders left and right each have 256 files each and then I can simply run an HTML comparison report.

Any help would be appreciated It. I googled this issue alot and found information but not an answer to my particular problem.

Comment: When you run `git status`, how many files are listed as staged ("Changes to be committed") ?

Comment: git status dose not give me a the number of files committed

Comment: it just gives me a list of file names in green and red

Comment: do you see a "Changes to be committed" list ?

Comment: Yes i do I see both and it looks like they are about the same number of file names

Comment: I don't see anything for untracked files files.

Comment: (good, all files under your repo are tracked :)  )

Comment: How many file names are listed under "Changes to be committed" ?

Comment: So ("Changes to be committed") and  ("Changes not staged for commmit") the number in each of these list are about the same however i dont get a number of how many are in each.

Comment: try : `git status -sb | grep "^[AMD]" | wc -l`

Comment: it shows that I have 176 files

Comment: it seems like i am missing 80 files. I wonder why that is happening unless the other 80 files there is no difference?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150009/discussion-between-jonathan-hofler-and-legec).

Comment: @LeGEC would you like to continue this in chat?

Comment: Do you know why it only show 176 files?

Comment: I am some what new to Git myself